# Send input values from root template phoenix

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, phoenix-live-view

I have this form in my file `root.html.leex`, and I want to handle this event but I don't know where I must handle it!

```html
<form phx-submit="topic-search" >
  <input type="text"
         name="req"
         placeholder="Search Topics, Posts,..."
         class="form-control"
         style="margin-top: 20px"/>
  <button type="submit"> </button>
</form>
```

Comment: If you have a `root.ex` module in the same direictory as your `root.html.leex`, that's where you should handle the event. Or if your `root.html.leex` template is being rendered by a different `.ex` file, that's where you should handle it

Comment: i don't have root.ex and also i don't know which .ex file render the root.html.ex template

Answer (score 1):

There is not a proper way of doing this mentioned anywhere, and what I am about to suggest is just a workaround to achieve what you want.

Make a simple module in you application

```
defmodule RootFormHelper do

  def handle_event("topic-search", params, socket) do
    // your code here
  end

end
```

After you create this module simply use this like, `use RootFormHelper, :handle_event` in all your live views which have `root.html.leex` set as there layout.

Your form will start working.

Comment: i will try your trick, thank you for your help i appreciate that.

Answer (score 0):

You need a `handle_event` function in your LiveView code. You can refer to [this](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix_live_view/form-bindings.html) for references regarding forms in LV.

Comment: yes i need a handle_event but where i need to write it ? because the root.html.leex file don't have the root.ex file in path : lib/app_web/templates/layout

Comment: Your router.ex should have the route where you want your LV, such as `live "/", Root `. You need to create the root.ex and declare the MyAppWeb.Root module. Look for examples online, it must use the `use MyAppWeb, :live_view ` That's where your code should live technically.

Comment: thanks for your help, i used another way to avoid that problem but i will try your solution. thnaks